# delete a folder that inside contains other folders

Tags: linux, unix

Hello I would like to ask if anyone knows how to delete a folder that inside contains other folders with Linux terminal being in another folder , if I am in the Documents / directory mine / I would like to delete a directory that is in documents with a single line command .
Thank you in advance .

Comment: the flag for recursive delete is -R

Comment: This should be posted on superuser.com. Anyway, `rm -r path` will do it.

Comment: yes, but I'm in / home / Documents / my/ and I need to delete a set of folders that are in / home / Documents/ how to do it with only a command line ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
rm -r /a/b/c/myfolder
```

option r would delete all the folder and its content recursively.

Comment: but I'm in / home / Documents / my and I need to delete a set of folders that are in / home / Documents ago as only a command line ?

Comment: It's not possible to be in child folder and deleting parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting several folders :

```
$ rm -rf {folder1/,folder2/,folder3/}
```